# Combine c# with js in aspx

Tags: javascript, c#

In a webform, how can I add to an href element the result of a javascript function?

I would need to append to the current url a parameter taken from a jsmethod.
Something like this perhaps:

```
<a href="<% HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()%>+"&param1"+jsmethod()" > link </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function callMethod() {
      return "123";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: There are nothing such as `combine c# with js`.

Answer (score 0):

you must manage it using javascript like this

```
<a href="" id="aNode"> link </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function callMethod() {
      return "123";
   }

   $(function() {
     var link = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()%>&param1=' + jsmethod(); // construct link

     $('#aNode').attr('href', link); // update link
   });
</script>
```